# example of $f\in L^2(B)$ but $f(x)|x|^{-1}\notin L^1(B)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, banach-spaces

Let $B$ denote the unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Find a function $f\in L^2(B)$ such that $f(x)|x|^{-1}\notin L^1(B)$.

I tried $|x|^{-1}\log|x|$ and $(|x|\log|x|)^{-1}$, but they did not work.

Comment: Why didn't they work? (One of the two should have almost worked.)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Try
$$
f(x)=(\log|x/2|)^{-1}|x|^{-1}
$$
That should fix up any problems you might have had.